Async Methods in TypeScript React E-Commerce App: Issue with Conversation Creation and Message Sending
I'm developing a TypeScript React E-Commerce platform with Java Spring Boot and PostgreSQL. When users submit a form, it should create a Conversation with an admin and send the form as a Message within that Conversation. However, it seems that when a Conversation entity is created, it's not yet saved in the database before the application attempts to send the message. As a result, the backend reports that the message has no associated conversation.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
const sendBuildAsMessage = async (formData: any) => {
    try {
        if (!currentUser) return;

        // Ensure conversation creation before sending message
        await createConversationForNewUser();

        // Wait for conversations state to update
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

        const messageContent = `${objectToString(formData)}`;

        // Use the first conversation after creation
        const activeConv = conversations[0];

        if (!activeConv) {
            console.log("No active conversation found");
            return;
        }

        await sendMessage({
            sender: currentUser,
            content: messageContent,
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            conversation: activeConv,
        });

        enqueueSnackbar("Build sent as message", { variant: "success" });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to send build as message:", error);
        enqueueSnackbar("Failed to send build as message", { variant: "error" });
    }
};

const createConversationForNewUser = async () => {
    try {
        let conversation: Conversation = {
            client: currentUser!,
            admin: currentUserAdmin!,
        };

        await createConversation(conversation);

        const response = await getUserConversations(parseInt(userId!));
        setConversations(response.data);
        enqueueSnackbar("Conversation created successfully", { variant: "success" });
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
        console.log("Conversation created successfully", response.data, conversations);
    } catch (error:any) {
        enqueueSnackbar("Failed to create conversation", { variant: "error" });
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};

I've attempted setting a Timeout and using .then/.catch instead of try/catch, but the methods don't synchronize. When I press the submit button for the first time, the method halts at "No active conversation found". However, pressing it a second time works as expected. What could be causing this issue?

You don't need any state, just return the conversations from createConversationForNewUser function
const sendBuildAsMessage = async (formData: any) => {
  try {
    if (!currentUser) return;

    // Ensure conversation creation before sending message
    const Conversations = await createConversationForNewUser(); // HERE

    const messageContent = `${objectToString(formData)}`;

    // Use the first conversation after creation
    const activeConv = Conversations[0];

    if (!activeConv) {
      console.log("No active conversation found");
      return;
    }

    await sendMessage({
      sender: currentUser,
      content: messageContent,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      conversation: activeConv,
    });

    enqueueSnackbar("Build sent as message", { variant: "success" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to send build as message:", error);
    enqueueSnackbar("Failed to send build as message", { variant: "error" });
  }
};

const createConversationForNewUser = async () => {
  try {
    let conversation: Conversation = {
      client: currentUser!,
      admin: currentUserAdmin!,
    };

    await createConversation(conversation);

    const response = await getUserConversations(parseInt(userId!));

    enqueueSnackbar("Conversation created successfully", { variant: "success" });
    console.log("Conversation created successfully", response.data, conversations);

    return response;

  } catch (error: any) {
    enqueueSnackbar("Failed to create conversation", { variant: "error" });
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};

